# latexmk with emacs only runs once instead of twice

Tags: emacs, latex

I have `latexmk` setup to run through `Auctex`.

I hit `crtl + c crtl + c` and the option `latexmk` is present.  When I run a file that has new bibliography items, it says after compiling that I need to run `latexmk` again to fix the dependencies.

Why isn't it running twice automatically?  Isn't that what it is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had to do with my options set in Emacs.

```
(defun run-latexmk ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
        (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
        (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-save-document "")
    (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
                 (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -file-line-error 
                                   -synctex=1' -pdf %O %S" 'TeX-master-file)
                 master-file))
    (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
        (TeX-next-error t)
      (progn
        (demolish-tex-help)
        (minibuffer-message "latexmk: done."))))
```

Original I had `%o %s`.  It has to be capital `O` and `S`.